# Make an AJAX request using $.ajax in MVC 4

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am trying to make an AJAX request using $.ajax in MVC 4 with Razor. I'm not sure how to implement it.

Using [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gLiWQkqUoVM) I was able to successfully make a link-driven call that returned data, but I can't seem to do the same thing from inside a jquery function. I can't seem to find any basic examples of how to do this.
This is what I am working with:

**HomeController.cs**

```
        public string test(){
             return "It works";
        }
```

**View.cshtml**

```
function inventory(dealerID) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("HomeController","test")',
        data: {dealerID: dealerID},
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data) {
            process(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You just need to make it an `ActionResult`.  Also, if you're using an Ajax POST, then the action needs to be marked with the `HttpPost` attribute.  Try this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult test(string dealerID)
{
    return Content("It works");
}
```

**Edit** Actually, there are a few other problems with the syntax.

1. `Url.Action` has the controller/action parameters in the wrong order -- should be "ActionName" first, then "ControllerName"
2. For `Url.Action`, if the controller class is "HomeController", then you need just "Home"
3. The JQuery options syntax is wrong -- should be `success: function(data) {}`.

---

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("test", "Home")',
    data: {dealerID: dealerID},
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: In your example, how does `test()` method get the `dealerId` from the JSON you are sending it? Should I assume it is passed as a parameter to the method, and you have simply omitted it?

Comment: @crush yes, exactly.  The MVC routing system is flexible enough to pull controller parameters from wherever they are available -- query string, post data, or route data.

Comment: @McGarnagle: How can you add C# code into a external js file? I know how I can do in a html file, but not for a js file.

Comment: You could do it (include it in the routing system), but doesn't seem advisable.  Better to factor the external dependencies out of the JS; or include the C# dependent JS as inline script, or as a partial view.