# MVC3—Trouble binding complex model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-ajax, model-binding, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I need to update a company class with an **IList** of addresses. These are my Data Models.

```
// Entity class Company — managed by Nhibernate
public class Company
{
  public virtual IList<Address> _addresses { get; set; }

  public Company()
  {
    _addresses = new List<Address>();
  }
}

// Entity class Address — managed by Nhibernate
public class Address
{
  public virtual string line1 { get; set; }
  public virtual string line1 { get; set; }
}
```

I am packing the data from the Entity class to the Viewmodel in the controller's GET action, and I am unpacking the data from the Viewmodel back to the Entity class in the controller's POST action.

Here are my View Models.

```
// Class CompanyRequest
public class CompanyRequest
{
  public IList<AddressRequest> AddressRequests;
}

//Class AddressRequests
public class AddressRequest
{
  public string line1 { get; set; }
  public string line1 { get; set; }
}
```

I am using a partial view to display each address box. For each **AddressRequest** in **AddressRequests** I pass the object to a partial view with the prefix set correctly.

```
for(var i = 0 ; i < AddressRequests.Count() ; i++)
{
  ViewData["Prefeix"] = String.Format("AddressRequests[{0}]", i);
  Html.RenderPartial("_addressPartial", AddressRequests[i]);
}
```

I need to be able to add an "**Add New Address**" button so that the user can add a new address to this list. This has to be done WITHOUT refreshing the page. When the user clicks that button, another address-box (same partial, I'm guessing) appears. Then the user edits the box and presses a "**Save**" button. This Save button is supposed to save the whole *Company* data, not just the *Address*.

Is there a way to do this? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that you use a client-side technology i.e. [javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) to dynamically load additional addresses in the UI, then pass the data back to the server side for processing via [ajax techniques](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_intro.asp) when they are ready to save.

There are plenty of javascript libraries out there that can perform ajax requests. I prefer the [jQuery library](http://jquery.com/).

Here are a number of articles on how to perform ajax with mvc:

- http://codebetter.com/petervanooijen/2010/01/18/why-choose-between-ajax-or-mvc-together-they-kiss-so-sweet/
- [Make an AJAX request using $.ajax in MVC 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13019778/make-an-ajax-request-using-ajax-in-mvc-4)
- http://weblogs.asp.net/srkirkland/archive/2009/09/08/using-jquery-ajax-methods-in-asp-net-mvc-get-and-getjson-vs-post.aspx

And of course: http://bit.ly/XWYE5P

Comment: Really lame, just discovered that stackoverflow doesn't allow you to post links to the Let Me Google That For You website. Oh well

Comment: Ah ha! Found a workaround leveraging a url compressor =P It lives on! http://bit.ly/XWYE5P

Comment: Figured it out. All I had to do was to use an AJAX link to hit a controller action asynchronously. Will post my entire code shortly, because I think not everywhere you see this done **without** jQuery.

Comment: @ChameeraDedduwage If you feel that my ajax answer was helpful and lead to the solution feel free to mark this as the answer. =P